# Reversed number in python doesn't pass validation

Tags: python

So here is the problem... I need to figure out how to reverse a number(integer) in python without using  string, loops of if-else statements.
So I find this code that allegebly is quite easy and understandable:

```
def write_backwards(n):
  
   reverse = 0
while (n > 0 ):
    reminder = n % 10
    reverse = ( reverse * 10 ) + reminder
    n = n // 10
    return reverse
```

But it failed on each validation.
Suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Indentation** is incorrect

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Also, ```return``` is inside the loop. So, only ```4``` is returned

Comment: maybe this is cheating, but`return int(str(n)[::-1])` would be much simpler -- convert `n` to a string, reverse the string, and convert it back to an int, rather than doing base-10 math tricks on the int.

Comment: @Samwise it seems like the instructions are clear on that point: `without using string`

Comment: @Tristanisha -- it seems like you are not supposed to use loops, but you have a `while` *loop*. Is that allowed?

Comment: The instructions specifically say not to use "string", not "strings" or "str".  I assume it's a prohibition against the `string` module and/or strangling yourself with your shoelace in an attempt to escape from this ridiculous assignment (there's literally no way to do this without loops in some form, lol).

Answer (score 1):

1. Indentation: Python is extremely sensitive to indentation. It uses that to separate blocks of code.
2. Your `return` statement should be outside the `while` loop. `return` marks the end of the function. So as soon as `return` is encountered, the function ends. So, you only get the first number - 4 as the output.

Ideally. Your code should be this.

```
def write_backwards(n):
  
    reverse = 0
    while (n > 0 ):
        reminder = n % 10
        reverse = ( reverse * 10 ) + reminder
        n = n // 10
    return reverse
print(write_backwards(1234))
```